# Getting Entry name 'classes.dex' collided error while building app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing this error every single week at least 4 times. It usually happens when I switch building my app from Phone to Emulator. And usually I have to clean project and invalidate cache/restart entire studio 4-10 times in a row in order to remove this error. Is there any normal way to fix this? I think this is clearly some Android Studio bug which is happening randomly and it is starting to slow me in development because I cant build my app for 30-40 minutes straight.

Sometimes I have to uninstall app from phone or emulator or completely wipe out emulator in order to fix this.

Full error:

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > Entry name 'classes.dex' collided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs when there exists a file with a same name. Do you have any signed apk in your releases folder? If it's there, delete it and it may stop colliding. If it persists, try Clean Project and generate a **signed** apk.

Comment: No, I dont have any.

Comment: I hope you're looking in ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk\release right?

Comment: yes I deleted those.

Comment: Mostly, it gets fixed using this solution. But in this case, try Clean Project and generate a **signed** apk.

Comment: Yeah it got fixed, but its still generated every time I switch from emulator to real device. So I have to manually remove that. Is there a way how to turn off automatically generating APK after each build?

Comment: See, if you build your APK, it has to get generated because it's the software (sadly), but you can design a batch file script to remove that. Happy to help! :)